# Update/PUT json with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have problem with update/PUT with angular 2. I create function updateMember() in member-detail.component.ts file. Function get object correct and send it to server, but when tslint code, cosole return some errors:

```
app/members/member-detail.component.ts(51,42): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Member[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Member'. Property '_id' is missing in type 'Member[]'.
app/members/member-detail.component.ts(53,17): error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/members/member-detail.component.ts(56,17): error TS7006: Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

> member.model

```
export class Member {
constructor(
    public _id: string,
    public name: string,
    public old: number
) { }
}
```

> members.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Member } from './member';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class MembersService {

private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/members';

constructor( private http: Http ) { }

...

updateMember(member: Member): Observable<Member[]> {
    let body = JSON.stringify( member );
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.put(`${this.apiUrl}/${member._id}`, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}


private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}


private handleError (error: Response | any) {

    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;

    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);

}


}
```

> member-detail.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Member } from './member';
import { MembersService } from './members.service';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'member-detail',
templateUrl: 'member-detail.component.html',
styleUrls: [ 'member-detail.component.css' ],
animations: [
    trigger('showContent', [
        transition('void => *', [
            animate(500, keyframes([
                style({opacity: 0, offset: 0}),
                style({opacity: 0.01, offset: 0.99}),
                style({opacity: 1, offset: 1}),
            ]))
        ])
    ])
]
})
export class MemberDetailComponent implements OnInit {

member: Member[];
errorMessage: string;

constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private membersService: MembersService ) { }

...

// function update but not tslint correct
updateMember() {
    this.membersService.updateMember(this.member)
        .subscribe(
            res => { 
                this.member = res;
            },
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `MemberDetailComponent`, you have a field named `member` which is of type `Member[]` which means `array` of `Member`'s

```
export class MemberDetailComponent implements OnInit {

member: Member[]; <---
```

and you are giving this as an input to the `updateMember` method

```
this.membersService.updateMember(this.member) <---
```

but it expects an input of type `Member`.

```
updateMember(member: Member): Observable<Member[]> { <---
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how I can refer member object from getMember method? 

`getMember() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
                this.membersService.getMember(params['id'])
                    .subscribe( 
                        member => this.member = member,
                        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
                    );
                    
            }
        });
        
    }`

Comment: @SebastianMałecki that is another question. Your question doesn't say anything about the `getMember()` method :/ Can you add it to the question so I can see it more clearly?

Comment: getMember method get object with member poperties from server and set this object in 'member: Member[]; <---' so How I Can refer this object .subscribe( member => this.member = **member** <-- to updateMember method?

Answer (score 0):

I find solution but It's not very well, so if somebody have better suggestion share it!

I added new variable `newMember: any;` inside `MemberDetailComponent()` and refer object from `this.member` to `newMember` and use it in `updateMember()`

Below my new code:

> member-detail.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Member } from './member';
import { MembersService } from './members.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'member-detail',
    templateUrl: 'member-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'member-detail.component.css' ],
    animations: [
        trigger('showContent', [
            transition('void => *', [
                animate(500, keyframes([
                    style({opacity: 0, offset: 0}),
                    style({opacity: 0.01, offset: 0.99}),
                    style({opacity: 1, offset: 1}),
                ]))
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
export class MemberDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    
    member: Member[];
    errorMessage: string;
    newMember: any; // new variable

    constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private membersService: MembersService ) { }

    ngOnInit() { 
        this.getMember();
    }

    getMember(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
                this.membersService.getMember(params['id'])
                    .subscribe( 
                        member => { this.member = member },
                        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error,
                        () => this.newMember = this.member
                    );
            }
        });
    }

    updateMember(): void {
        this.membersService.updateMember(this.newMember)
            .subscribe(
                res => this.newMember = res,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error,
                () => this.getMember()
            );
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Look, you are giving a `Member[]` to a method that expects a `Member`. Remove the `[]` if you don't want it to be an array. So make member -> `member: Member` not `member: Member[]`

Comment: Yes it's exacly what I need. I use in `members.service` `Observable<Member[]>` instead `Observable<Member>` and recive some errors in `member-detail.component`. Now I understand how it works. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)